# How to attach a rtf or doc file with Blackberry Application

Tags: blackberry

I have requirement to attach a doc file or a .rtf file with my project source code as a resource.
I want to invoke it on application installation time after saving permission.
I am working on a backgroung application not on a Ui application.

I dont have no idea about how to attach these files with source code and use them.

Answer (score 1):

You can treat these files as a resource to the project and place them in the resource folder and package the project.

Thanks

Naveen M